# ¿Cómo cambio la imagen de un Slide en ViewPager con base en el idioma?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

Esta es mi clase `IntroActivity`

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layuots;
private Button btn_next, btn_skip;
private IntroManager introManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    introManager = new IntroManager(this);
    if(!introManager.Check()){
        launchHomeScreem();
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_intro);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_bots);
    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn_skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);

    layuots = new int[]{
            R.layout.slide1,
            R.layout.slide2,
            R.layout.slide3
    };

    addButtonsDots(0);

    viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPage);

    btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchHomeScreem();
        }
    });

    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if(current<layuots.length)
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            else
                launchHomeScreem();
        }
    });

}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPage = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addButtonsDots(position);

        if(position == layuots.length - 1){
            btn_next.setText(R.string.start);
            btn_skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            btn_next.setText(R.string.next);
            btn_skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
private void addButtonsDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layuots.length];
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(18);
        dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.do_active));
        linearLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.no_activo));
}

private int getItem(int i){
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1;
}

private void launchHomeScreem(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class));
    finish();
}

public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ViewPageAdapter(){

    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layuots[position],container,false);
        final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);

        String idioma = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        String idiomav2 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
            iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
        else
            iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layuots.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view ==  object;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
}
```

He aqué mi XML del `IntroActivity`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/screen3"
tools:context="com.softim.beachesofmexico.IntroActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager_intro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt_titulo_slides"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/txt_titulo_slides"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shadowColor="#000"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:shadowDx="0.5"
    android:shadowDy="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_button"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_button"
    android:text="@string/skip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Me envia el siguiente error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                 Process: com.softim.beachesofmexico, PID: 12637
>                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                     at com.softim.beachesofmexico.IntroActivity$ViewPageAdapter.instantiateItem(IntroActivity.java:156)
>                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
>                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
>                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
>                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
>                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
>                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
>                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
>                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
>                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
>                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
>                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
>                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
>                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
>                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

No estoy seguro de qué lo ocasiona, he visto otras preguntas pero no encuentro por qué o cómo deberia hacer este tipo de cambio.

Esto es el primer slide

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:background="@mipmap/fondo_slides"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_titulo_s1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_titulo_s1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion1_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_s1_i1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_estate_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/select_state" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion2_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_s1_i2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_newBeach_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/new_beach" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion3_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_s1_i3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_send_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/more_details" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Esto es el segundo slide

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@mipmap/fondo_slides2"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/titulo_slide2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_indicacion2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion1_s2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_s2_i2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img_estate_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/location_maps" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Esto es el tercer slide

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:background="@mipmap/fondo_slides3"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/titulo_slide3"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liner_indicacion1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion1_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/desc_slide3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img_estate_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/llenar_fields" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion2_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/desc_slide32"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_choose_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/choose_imagen" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_indicacion3_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_i3_s3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_send_s3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/send_beach" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Asegura que en los layouts slide1.xml, slide2.xml , y slide3.xml se encuentre el ImageView , que son los que se inflan y de donde se obtiene la referencia del ImageView. Agregué respuesta.

Comment: Gracias eso era, ya he cambiado los id de todos los **ImageView** para que sean iguales, y el efectivamente ya los infla correctamente. _solo una duda_ como haria eso si en un slide solo tengo un **ImageView** y en los otros 2 si tengo los 3 **ImageView** @Jorgesys

Comment: agregué un ejemplo de como realizarías la validación, si existe el elemento agregas imagen. si no existe no realizas acción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

El problema es que en tu layout que intentas inflar en este punto (`layuots[position]`):

```
 View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layuots[position],container,false);
```

no existe el `ImageView` con id `img_estate_s1`:

```
 final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);
```

---

La solución es asegurar que en los layouts `slide1.xml`, `slide2.xml` , y `slide3.xml` se encuentre el `ImageView` con id `img_estate_s1`

---

> ¿Como validar si en un slide solo tengo un ImageView y en los otros 2
>   si tengo los 3 ImageView?

Podrías validar simplemente agregar la imagen si se encuentra la referencia dentro del layout, si no, simplemente no intentar realizar nada con ellos,

ejemplo:

```
...
...
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layuots[position],container,false);

        final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);
        final ImageView iv_photo2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s2);
        final ImageView iv_photo3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s3);

        String idioma = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        String idiomav2 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

        if(iv_photo != null){ //Valida imageView 1
          if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
              iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
          else
              iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
        }

       if(iv_photo2 != null){ //Valida imageView 2
          if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
              iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
          else
              iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
        }

         if(iv_photo3 != null){ //Valida imageView 3
          if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
              iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
          else
              iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
        }


        container.addView(view);

        return view;

...
...
```

Comment: De hecho si esta en los slide1, 2 y 3, por eso es que no entiendo el error

Comment: Ups, estaba segur@ que eso era el error ya que obtiene la vista de la cual obtiene la instancia del ImageView  : "view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);"  mmm realiza un clean > build y trata de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias eso era, ya he cambiado los id de todos los **ImageView** para que sean iguales, y el efectivamente ya los infla correctamente. _solo una duda_ como haria eso si en un slide solo tengo un **ImageView** y en los otros 2 si tengo los 3 **ImageView** @Jorgesys

Comment: @TimoRuiz tu simplemente usas el mismo layout y dones los imagenes segun la posición que se te pasa el método `instantiateItem`. Te dejo código.

Comment: @TimoRuiz podrías validar que únicamente si la instancia del ImageView tiene valor null no intente agregar imagen: final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);   if(iv_photo != null){agrega imagen}else{ no agregas imagen } agrego en mi respuesta...

Comment: @TimoRuiz agregué ejemplo de validación.

Comment: Es justo como lo tengo ahora, pero no funciona puesto que la imagen en las 3 slides, (slide1 con 3 imagenes, slide 2 con 1 imagen, slide 3 con 3 imagenes) cada imagen es diferente en cada slide, entonces ahi me queda otra validacion de ver cual slide se muestra y asi asignar la imagen adecuada

Comment: Solo agrega que posición es (position) en base a eso sabrás que layout se esta cargando. Solo debes tener en cuenta que position == 0 es slide1,  position == 1 es slide2, y position == 2 es slide3,

Comment: GRacias ya lo he hecho como lo muestro en mi respuesta, lo dejare abierto por si hay alguna otra opcion menos sucia y alguin lo quiere agregar. Gracias igual por el apoyo.

Comment: Excelente Timo, saludos ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el siguiente código te devuelve `null`:

```
   final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_estate_s1);
```

Donde definiste el `android:id="@+id/img_estate_s1"`?

Puedes hacer lo siguiente. En vez de guardar el id de los layouts en tu arreglo, guardas los recursos gráficos:

```
layuots = new int[]{
        R.mipmap.imagen1,
        R.mipmap.imagen2,
        R.mipmap.imagen3
};
```

Luego puedes obtener los imágenes con

```
Drawable resImg = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(layuots[position]);
```

o, obteniendo tu `ImageView` con `findById(R.id.img_estate_1)` (debe funcionar si el id es unico) y luego usar:

```
 ic_photo.setImageDrawable(resImg);
```

o simplemente

```
 ic_photo.setImageResource(layuots[position]);
```

Y ahora viene tu feliz navidad. - ***drumroll*** - Si lo haces así, simplemente puedes colocar tus alternativas para "es" en `mipmap-es` y el resto hace Android para ti ;).

Comment: esta definido en el slide   @PeterSmith `<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_estate_s1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/select_state" />`

Comment: Y como sabe el `ViewPager` (que es el contexto donde buscas el id) que debería tener este ImageView como vista hijo?

Comment: Entonces como deberia hacer ese cambio de imagen? Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Gracias probare con ellos ya te comento como va @peter

Comment: creo que me perdi no captando como manejas los layouts de los imagenes. Puedes compartir los tres xml en tu pregunta?

Comment: Listo ahi estan @Stefan Nolde

Comment: Ok, el problema con los id es que tienen que ser únicos en tu proyecto. Te dejé una alternativa que solamente usa un layout para todas las imagenes.

Comment: Eso lo pense pero no crei que fuera eso posible o no para mipmap-es

Comment: Creo que no amigo, hay detalle, tengo 3 slides, (slide1 con 3 imagenes, slide 2 con 1 imagen, slide 3 con 3 imagenes) cada imagen es diferente en cada slide, entonces al agregar los `mipmap` eso no cuadra con la cantidad de slides @Stefan

Comment: Dices que los layouts de los slides son estructuralmente distintos? Entonces tienes que asegurarte que los id son unicos y simplemente eligir los id en otra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ya he encontrado la respuesta, aunque a decir verdad no me gusto demasiado por el mal uso del codigo, si hay alguna otra solucion se los agradezco.
Solo modifique los id de los ImageView de los tres Slides para que fueran iguales para todos.
Slide 1 asi quedo

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/select_state" />
```

en el segundo slide

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@id/img1_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/location_maps" />
```

en el tercer Slide

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@id/img1_s1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_playas_cat_desc"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/llenar_fields" />
```

y en la clase edite solo el `instantiateItem` de la siguiente forma

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layuots[position], container, false);
        String idioma = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        String idiomav2 = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img1_s1);
        final ImageView iv_photo2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2_s1);
        final ImageView iv_photo3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img3_s1);

        if(position == 0) {
            if (iv_photo != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo2 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo3 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
        }
        if(position == 1) {
            if (iv_photo != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.location_maps);
                else
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo2 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo3 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
        }
        if(position == 2) {
            if (iv_photo != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.llenar_fields);
                else
                    iv_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo2 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
            if (iv_photo3 != null) {
                if (idioma.equals("es") || idiomav2.equals("Spanish"))
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.new_beach);
                else
                    iv_photo3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select_state);
            }
        }

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

gracias por las respuestas @Jorgesys y @Stefan Nolde